# MySQL Request for review on hourly average query as it's working only for one week

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL DB (Version 5.5.31) say table1 with description:

```
mysql> desc table1;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| ts                 | timestamp    | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| type               | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| calculated_percent | int(3)       | NO   |     | 100                 |       |
| used               | int(11)      | NO   |     | 100                 |       |
| available          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 100                 |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

I am trying to write a MySQL query which would get average of calculated_percent, by checking ts. ts should be between "current time" and "current time - 1 hour". This same time slot will be checked for past 6 weeks for the same day of the week.

Query I have written and it's output is:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> type,
    -> IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), AVG(calculated_percent), 0) as Avg1,
    -> IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 2 week), AVG(calculated_percent), 0) as Avg2,
    -> IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 3 week), AVG(calculated_percent), 0) as Avg3,
    -> IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 4 week), AVG(calculated_percent), 0) as Avg4,
    -> IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 5 week), AVG(calculated_percent), 0) as Avg5,
    -> IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 6 week), AVG(calculated_percent), 0) as Avg6
    -> FROM table1
    -> WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week)
    -> AND HOUR(ts) = HOUR(now())
    -> GROUP BY type;
+-------------------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+
| type              | Avg1 | Avg2 | Avg3 | Avg4 | Avg5 | Avg6    |
+-------------------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+
| O                 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 26.1663 |
| R                 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 34.1647 |
| S                 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |  1.7913 |
+-------------------+------+------+------+------+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.08 sec)

mysql>
```

Can you please help me to find out why I am missing data for weeks 1 to 5?
When I checked using an independent query for week 1, I do get data as expected and I know data is present for every week.

The query (that I used to check) and it's output is:

```
mysql> SELECT type, AVG(calculated_percent) as Avg1 FROM table1
    -> WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week)
    -> GROUP BY type;
+-------------------+---------+
| type              | Avg1    |
+-------------------+---------+
| O                 | 36.9167 |
| R                 | 46.5833 |
| S                 |  4.5833 |
+-------------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "old" query, you filter the rows to allow only those to be considered - in your "new" query you allow rows, that should NOT be considered, which gives this strange result depending on the order in which   the rows are evaluated. In other RDBMS you might get an "invalid use of aggregate" syntax error instead of the plainly wrong result.

Depending on the size of your table you could either run your "old" query 6 times (with oviously adapted intervals) or try to rephrase, as the AVG function will give bad results, if you allow not matching rows:

```
SELECT
  type,
  sum1/count1 AS avg1,
  sum2/count2 AS avg2,
  sum3/count3 AS avg3,
  sum4/count4 AS avg4,
  sum5/count5 AS avg5,
  sum6/count6 AS avg6
FROM (
  SELECT
    type,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum1,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 1 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count1,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum2,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 2 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count2,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum3,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 3 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count3,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum4,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 4 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count4,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum5,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 5 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count5,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), calculated_percent, 0)) as sum6,
    SUM(IF (ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week) AND ts <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 week), 1, 0)) as count6
  FROM table1
  WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour), interval 6 week)
  GROUP BY type
) AS baseview
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugen. This works perfect (just corrected some typos like changed count1 to count2, count3, etc in select and changed sum3 to sum2 as it was repeated). I have another question, if I avoid using "GROUP BY type" and create 3 separate queries for each type (O, R and S) is there any way I can skip min and max values from the 6 weeks and calculate average of remaining 4 weeks? As these values are in row instead of column, I couldn't find a way to use MIN/MAX functions there. I am searching if creating temp table could help in any way here.